# Authentication successful but unable to retrieve and list Azure AD Users using Azure Golang SDK

Tags: azure, go, sdk

I am trying to use Azure Golang SDK to pull the list of Azure AD users.

Few things to Note:
1. Authentication is successful. "Authorization successful." is displayed when I use below code to fetch bearer token for Azure SPN.
   This is pretty much vanilla code picked from Azure-Go-SDK repo.

```
//GetGraphAuthorizer gets an OAuthTokenAuthorizer for graphrbac API.

func GetGraphAuthorizer(fs auth.FileSettings) (autorest.Authorizer, error) {
    if graphAuthorizer != nil {
        return graphAuthorizer, nil
    }

    var a autorest.Authorizer
    var err error

    a, err = getAuthorizerForResource(grantType(), Environment().GraphEndpoint, fs)

    if err == nil {
        // cache
        graphAuthorizer = a
        fmt.Println("Authorization successful.")
    } else {
        graphAuthorizer = nil
        fmt.Println ("Authorization failed.")
    }

    return graphAuthorizer, err
}
```

Defined a wrapper on around **GetGraphAuthorizer** function to instantiate **userClient** object:

```
func getADUserClient(fs auth.FileSettings) graphrbac.UsersClient {
    userClient := graphrbac.NewUsersClient(azure.GetTenantId(fs))
    a, _ := azure.GetGraphAuthorizer(fs)
    userClient.Authorizer = a
    userClient.AddToUserAgent(azure.UserAgent())
    return userClient
}
```

Then I use the token to list users in Azure AD in below function:

```
    adUserClient := getADUserClient(fs) 
    // if auth failed, then it should've displayed the failure message here but prints "Authorization successful instead"
    for list, err := adUserClient.ListComplete(context.Background(), ""); list.NotDone(); err = list.Next() {
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Print("got error while traversing User list: ", err)
            } 
            i := list.Value()
            fmt.Println(*i.DisplayName)
            fmt.Println(*i.GivenName)

        }
```

No output what so ever!!

FYI:- I have users in Azure tenant.
     I have granted SPN access to Graph API.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure but for some reason I had to grant Azure SPN "Delegated" permission to:
Directory.ReadWrite.All
Groups.ReadWrite.All

Surprisingly, Once the program listed users, I removed above "Delegated" permissions off SPN and just left the Application permissions and it continues to work!